# Magento Coding Issues with Return Value

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to get my magento store to list what size a specific shirt is, but it's only returning a numeral instead of large, medium, ect.  Below is my code.

```
<?php if($_product->getSize()): ?>
<p>Size: <?php echo $_product->getSize();?> </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_product->getAttributeText('size')`, the attribute might not be *size*, to get a list view the out put of `$_product->getAttributes()`.

Comment: When i use the getAttributeText('Size') or 'size', nothing will show up.  Example below:                                                     <?php if($_product->getSize()): ?>
                <p>Size: <?php echo $_product-> getAttributeText('size');   //SIZE TEST?> </p>
                <?php endif; ?>